# PHP move_uploaded_file changing the name of the stored file?

Tags: php

I got some code from [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

While this code works, it uploads the original file name to the server. I have a random string generator that i want to name the files with:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters =     '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
   return $randomString;
}
```

So,

```
<?php 
session_start();

$picName = generateRandomString();
$_SESSION['picName'] = $picName;
?>
```

Where $picName is getting sent to the database, and we will use the $_SESSION['picName'] on the upload2.php file.

Here is the html:

```
<form method="post" action="upload2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
<input type="file" name="img" />
</form>
```

And here is upload2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$picName = $_SESSION['picName'];
$target_path = "files/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);  


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the drivers licence picture, please try again!";
}
?>
```

So the question is, where in upload2.php do I need to set the new name ($picname) to change the final name of the file?

Comment: [Checking the documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) you can see how to replace the uploaded file name.

Comment: The second argument is the name of the file you want to move to. If `$picname` is what you want it to be, then that's what you should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this line,

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {...
```

Where `$target_path` is `"files/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);`.

Few errors:

- `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']` is wrong. You've named the input field as `img`, so it should be `$_FILES['img']['name']`
- Look at your `$target_path`, you're uploading the file with same file name.

To upload a file with a **new file name**, do this:

```
$target_path = "files/";
$target_path = $target_path . $picName . "." . strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['img']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Comment: @Justin You named the input field as `img`, which I missed earlier. I've updated my answer. Test your application with the updated code snippet.

Comment: Well it says it works but no files were actually uploaded.

Comment: I am also only using $_SESSION['picname'] instead of $picName = $_SESSION['picname'];

Comment: @Justin Do `echo $target_path;` before your `move_uploaded_file()` statement and check whether it's the correct path or not.

Comment: "files/.jpgThe file has been uploaded" So aparently the session var isnt being carried over correctly

Comment: @Justin Instead of using session, use `generateRandomString()` function directly in your *upload2.php* page i.e instead of doing `$picName = $_SESSION['picName'];`, do `$picName = generateRandomString();` in your *upload2.php* page.

Comment: Ok so instead of having the upload2.php file and trying to use the session to pass the name of the file I just put the code onto the original page and it works perfectly now! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `$target_path` variable just needs to include the full filepath and name you want to use for the file.  SO code is as simple as:

```
$target_path = 'files/' . $whatever_random_string;
```

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined index
and
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy()
and 
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpn3Wjvf'

Comment: also  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: which i think is talking about the session var picName

Comment: @Justin I am guessing you are trying to write the file to somewhere where you have no permissions.  I don't know anything about `$_SESSION['picName']` as you didn't to about this at all in your question and sounds like a different problem.

Comment: Mike, I already changed permissions on the server to send files. I got the example from the link the the original post to work but I couldn't change the name when it got sent to the server.

Comment: Well thanks for trying to help me but someone else has solved the issue! I would be very grateful if you upvoted my post so I can upvote other people posts!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this example and working properly.

Get the extention of the origianl image, and change the name.

```
$ImageName = basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
$Last4 = substr($ImageName, -4);//Get only last 4 caracter of string.
$extention = str_replace("jpeg",".jpeg", $Last4);//We have jpg, jpeg, gif, png , so the only problem is jpeg so we replace jpeg for .jpeg :)

$picName = $_SESSION['picName'];
$target_path = "./files/";    

//Load image on server.
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_path . $picName . $extention);
```

Comment: Well, its not giving any errors and it says it uploaded but the file isnt showing up in files/.

Comment: change it and put it separetly: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_path . $picname . $extention);

Comment: Thanks for the help but someone has solved the problem! Thanks so much for trying to help me! I would be very grateful if you up voted my post so I can get some reputation so i can up vote other peoples posts!

Comment: no problem friend, i have give a posetive vote.  I wish you good look.